# condition in DateTime change Foreground in Listbox (Binding)

Tags: datetime, binding, listbox, conditional-statements, foreground

I need to change the colors of the items in a listBox, these were added by a class and the XAML use binding between certain hours of the day I need the color of the items that are added to the ListBox is changed, the example is in the comment, use DateTime for it, but no way I work. 
Greetings from Colombia

```
public class Class1
{

    public String Link { get; set; }
    public String Horario { get; set; }
    public String Foto { get; set; }


    public Class1(String link, String horario, String foto)
    {
        this.Link = link;
        this.Horario = horario;
        this.Foto = foto;

    }
}
}
    private void MainPage_loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        DateTime dt11AM = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 11, 0, 0);
        DateTime dt1130AM = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 11, 30, 0);
        List<Class1> milista = new List<Class1>();
        milista.Add(new Class1("B1", "L/S 5:00 am-11:00 pm D/F 5:00 am-11:00 pm", "Images/Zona_B.jpg"));
        milista.Add(new Class1("B2", "L/S 5:00 am-11:00 pm D/F 5:00 am-11:00 pm", "Images/Zona_B.jpg"));
        milista.Add(new Class1("B3", "L/S 5:00 am-11:00 pm D/F 5:00 am-11:00 pm", "Images/Zona_B.jpg"));
        milista.Add(new Class1("B5", "L/S 5:00 am-11:00 pm D/F 5:00 am-11:00 pm", "Images/Zona_B.jpg"));
        milista.Add(new Class1("B6", "L/S 5:00 am-11:00 pm D/F 5:00 am-11:00 pm", "Images/Zona_B.jpg"));
        milista.Add(new Class1("B7", "L/S 5:00 am-11:00 pm D/F 5:00 am-11:00 pm", "Images/Zona_B.jpg"));
        milista.Add(new Class1("B8", "L/S 5:00 am-11:00 pm D/F 5:00 am-11:00 pm", "Images/Zona_B.jpg"));//
        milista.Add(new Class1("B9", "L/S 7:00 am-8:00 pm D/F 5:00 am-11:00 pm", "Images/Zona_B.jpg"));// green color "b9" and "L/S 7:00 am-11:00 pm D/F 5:00 am-11:00 pm"
        milista.Add(new Class1("B10", "L/S 6:00 am-11:00 pm D/F 5:00 am-11:00 pm", "Images/Zona_B.jpg"));//Red , only "B10" element
        ListaObjeto.ItemsSource = milista;    


      //if (DateTime.Now < dt11AM)
    // ListaObjeto.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0);
     // ListBoxItem.ForegroundProperty = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow)); 
       }
```

Comment: what is the result of this current code?

Comment: Result the listbox in the aplication